# postgres: cursor "xxx" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql, procedure

I'm new in pspgsql and I'm unable to understand why the cursor does not exists on fetch. Can anyone tell me what is wrong, please?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.import_candles(
    IN in_source varchar(16),
    IN in_timeframe varchar(3),
    IN in_symbol varchar(8),
    IN in_bulk integer DEFAULT 10000)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare
    bulkCounter int;
    rec_input record;
    cur_input cursor(psource varchar(16), ptimeframe varchar(3), psymbol varchar(8)) for
        select distinct time, open, high, low, close, volume
        from candlesticks_input
        where source = psource and timeframe = ptimeframe and symbol = psymbol;
begin
    bulkCounter := 0;
    open cur_input(in_source, in_timeframe, in_symbol);
    
    loop
        fetch cur_input into rec_input;
        exit when not found;

        -- more code here ...
        
        bulkCounter = bulkCounter + 1;
        if MOD(bulkCounter,in_bulk) = 0 then
            commit;
        end if;
    
    end loop;
    
    close cur_input;
    commit;
end
$BODY$;
```

When I call this function:

```
call import_candles('MY_SOURCE', 'H1', 'EURUSD');
```

I got the error:

```
ERROR:  cursor "cur_input" does not exist
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function import_candles(character varying,character varying,character varying,integer) line 14 at FETCH
SQL state: 34000
```

Comment: maybe you have to do `open cur_input(psource:=in_source, ptimeframe:=in_timeframe, psymbol:=in_symbol);` like [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/plpgsql-cursor/)?

Comment: @Matthias, you are right! I did your suggestion and all works fine! tks a lot!

Only one observation: the tutorial that you suggest me has a example with: 
`open cur_films(p_year);`. When I can open a cursor without name the parameters and when I can't?

Comment: very good, please accept my answer (and optionally upvote). I don't know when you need the parameter and when you don't, I would guess maybe when the variable names are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
open cur_input(psource:=in_source, ptimeframe:=in_timeframe, psymbol:=in_symbol);
```

like shown [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/plpgsql-cursor/)